# Why can't I use jQuery in amazon (in console)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

using firebug console in firefox for example when execute this script

```
$("body").css("border","4px solid red");
```

it will return an error with message:

```
TypeError: $("body") is null
```

same in chrome the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

any one knows why? and how to use it?

Comment: Well, obviously $ is not a function so either the page doesn't have jQuery loaded or it is removing the $ variable as a reference to jQuery. After a quick check `$` is undefined, `jQuery` is still valid. They are probably doing `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: `jQuery` can be used in place of `$`, or you can define `$=jQuery`

Comment: @JulienCh. this is the best solution thanks if u can add answer to mark it as the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of Amazon, only `jQuery` is defined, not `$`, you can use the `jQuery()` function instead of `$()` or simply define `$=jQuery`

Note the version of jQuery is an old one: 1.2.6

**Edit**

`$=jQuery.noConflict()` sounds even cleaner

Answer (score 4):

`$` is not a reference to `jQuery` at that site.

It does appear as though an old version jQuery is loaded...

You can tell by doing this...

```
jQuery.fn.jquery; // 1.2.6
```

---

Also, keep in mind that consoles are often not a pure environment. If there's no other code using the `$` variable, they may take it over.

It appears as though Firebug does exactly that. I'm guessing it's a shortcut for `document.getElementById`, which will return `null` if there's no element with the ID `"body"`.

The error is different in Chrome because `$` is apparently `undefined`, so you're trying to use `undefined` as a function.

Answer (score 0):

As "am not i am" stated, Amazon either doesn't use jQuery or doesn't alias it as "$".

If you want to use jQuery on a site like that, you can use a jQuerify-ing bookmarklet like this one:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet

to add jQuery (with the standard "$" alias) to the page temporarily.